# Cannot mount bootable Windows 10 drive

Tags: macos, startup

I am trying to make a bootable USB with the **dd** command since Boot Camp does not work. If I execute this command:

```
sudo dd if=Win10.iso of=/dev/disk1 bs=1m
```

I get a disk formatted as Universal Disk Format with a GUID partition scheme making it unbootable. The way I changed it to Master Boot Record (FDisk) partition scheme was to erase the failed USB contents, change it to FDisk, and run the dd command with **disk1s1** instead of **disk1** (**disk1s1** was the identifier of the only partition on the USB).

What that has done was made an unmounted partition called **disk1s1**, formatted in FAT and with the FDisk partition scheme, but it is unmountable and I cannot boot from it. When I try mounting it, nothing happens, and the terminal command output is `Volume on disk1s1 failed to mount`. I cannot repair disk and Verify disk says `Invalid BS_jmpBoot in boot block: 000000`

As far as I can remember, Ubuntu's bootable USB showed similar behavior with the unmountable disk, but it was detectable by rEFInd.

UPDATE:

The error message I get in VirtualBox is:

```
VD: error VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED opening image file '/Users/username/RawWinDisk.vmdk' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).
VD: error VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED opening image file '/Users/username/RawWinDisk.vmdk' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).
Failed to open image '/Users/username/RawWinDisk.vmdk' in read-write mode (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).
Failed to attach driver below us! Not supported. (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).
AHCI: Failed to attach drive to Port0 (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).
```

---

I am using OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks), and I have a 13-inch, Mid 2012 MBP

Comment: I'm by no means any kind of terminal expert, but does this line help any towards the format? from a script I use to generate MBR SD cards - `do shell script "diskutil eraseDisk \"MS-DOS\" " & diskName & " MBRFormat " & BSD_disk`

Comment: @Tetsujin What does the line do? Does it erase and format as FAT? When I delete and redo the `dd` command, it does not stay as FAT, but formats itself into UDF and GUID again.

Comment: yes, it makes sure they format as MBR/FAT32 - otherwise they format as GUID/FAT32 which does not work for my end purpose

Comment: What is the reason you cannot use the Boot Camp Assistant?

Comment: @user3439894 Error message saying "Bootcamp only supports windows 7 or higher" I found a fix with adding my model ID to the plist, but that crashes Bootcamp on launch

Comment: Your initial command is correct. Window 10 ISOs contain a full disk. You can't write that to a partition, it has to be the full disk. As to why it didn't boot? I think it may be because it's formatted with UDF, which your Mac doesn't expect to find on a USB stick. I have had an issue with that in the past... I usually use a method that removes the need for writing the ISO to a disk first, but people have had problems following my steps in the past, so I'm hesitant to post it again. If you want to try it though, I suppose I could...

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard Thanks for the info. Before, I tried to mount an ISO file and copy contents, but 1 file did not copy, and I got a message "A media driver that your computer needs is missing...". I think that you could post your method as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if anything goes wrong! I have tried to update everything for the latest version of VirtualBox, but I may have messed up somewhere...

The method I use relies on VirtualBox for its operation. Follow these steps:

1. Install the latest version of VirtualBox from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads. Make sure it installs the command line tools.
2. Once installed, open it and create a new VM by clicking "New" on the top left.
3. Select the type to be "Microsoft Windows", and select the version as "Windows 10 (64 bit)", then give it a name of your choosing.
4. Select "Do not add a virtual hard drive". We will be creating one on our own for our purposes. Click "Create".
5. If you have not created a partition for Windows, do so now in Disk Utility. Click on the disk (not any partition) in the sidebar, and click the partitions tab. Then click the "+" button, and make a new partition as large as you want it to be. 30GB is a good minimum size.
6. Now we have to open the Terminal. Type the following command: `diskutil list`. From the list of disks, make a note of the disk identifier in the last column that belongs to the partition you created for Windows. We will need this in the next step.
7. Run the command `sudo chown $USER /dev/disk#s#`. Replace disk#s# with the identifier from earlier. Enter your password and push return. Also run `sudo chown $USER /dev/disk#s1`. Use the same identifier, but replace the last number with a 1. Also run `sudo chown $USER /dev/disk#` using the first half of your identifier (minus the s# part).
8. Unmount the disk by typing `diskutil unmount /dev/disk#s#` using your identifier.
9. Now we have to create the disk for the VM to use for installation. Run the command `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ~/RawWinDisk.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/disk# -partitions 1,#`. Replace "disk#" with the appropriate first half of the identifier from earlier, and replace the second # sign with the last number in your identifier.
10. Unmount the disk again `diskutil unmount /dev/disk#s#`, using your identifier.
11. Now you should have a ".vmdk" file in your home folder. Go back into VirtualBox, select the VM you created, and click "Settings". Select the "Storage" tab, add an IDE controller by clicking the second "+" icon at the bottom, click on the "IDE" controller and click the second "+" sign directly to right of the controller (the hover text is "Add Hard Disk").
12. Click "Choose existing disk", and navigate to the VMDK we just created, which should be in your home folder. Click it and select "Open". Now you should see the newly added disk just below the "IDE" controller.
13. Click on "Empty" just below the "SATA" controller, check "Live CD/DVD", and click the little CD icon next to "SATA Port #".
14. Click "Choose Virtual Optical Disk File...", navigate to your ISO, and open it.
15. Start the VM and install windows on the 30G partition.
16. When the installation is done and you're logged in, shut down Windows and you should see the disk created by Windows appear on the desktop. You can get the Boot Camp drivers for your laptop from https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720?locale=en_US. Put this on a flash drive formatted as ExFAT or FAT so Windows can read it.
17. You should now be able to reboot into Windows by holding alt down, or selecting the disk in Startup Disk preferences.

Make sure you update your BootCamp with Apple Software Update once you have BootCamp installed on the Windows side. These are technically Windows 8.1 drivers, which should work well enough for you to at least connect to the internet and get the latest version.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't look like a hard to follow method as you said. I am trying it now :)

Comment: I get the error result code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), and a recurring VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED

Comment: At which step ?

Comment: Upon starting the virtual machine. Also, there is a RawWinDisk and a RawWinDisk-pt. I used the one without pt   http://imgur.com/bTf7IRD . I'll try re-installing VirtualBox

Comment: Strange... I'll see if I can figure out the issue here.

Comment: Doing a clean install of VirtualBox as I installed it earlier. Might be due to update failing... I would interpret VERR as version. That did not work.

Comment: Actually, VERR just means VirtualBox Error.

Comment: I edited the question with the full report. The discussion is getting long. Shouldn't we go to a chat room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29880/discussion-between-william-t-froggard-and-thebro21).

Comment: It worked. It installs, but its not detected as bootable. But thats something for a different session